# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for a class in the project

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

Android is throwing NoClassDefFoundError for ~1% of my users, no specific SDK version.

It's happening In my activity in the onCreate function when it try's to get an instance to a Singleton class i have in my project.

The singleton class it self doesn't reference any libs jar.

I tried on same devices it's heppening (e.g. SGH-T989) with no success.

Edit: adding the stack trace

```
at com.myapp.activities.RootActivity.getLoaderInstance(RootActivity.java:450)
at com.myapp.activities.RootActivity.doOnCreate(RootActivity.java:215)
at com.myapp.android.activities.AbstractActivity.onCreate(AbstractActivity.java:130)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: could You please post logcat output?

Comment: Since I cant reproduce i dont have a logcat out put, but i added the stacktrace

Comment: Do you have a static code block in your singleton? Question why I'm asking is, that if you have, and it contains errors the class can't be loaded. May be you can paste in your Singleton code here (or at least the static parts).

Comment: I had some static code, it didnt contain errors... but i changed it's modifier just in case.
Will let you know if the problem is solved.

Comment: Seems like making it non static solved the issue.
Thanks!